# Упасть в обморок восторга - годится как авторская находка или... воля хозяина?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Предлагаю "от" - и чувствую, что лезу грязной лапкой в свежий образ...

Comment: Рассказывают, такое реально случалось с жёнами советских дипломатов, впервые зашедших в заграничный магазин. Восторг они при этом испытывали (естественно, **от**) или ужас от нехватки денег на всё сразу, установить уже невозможно.

Comment: Пожалуйста, старайтесь избегать создания новых меток.

Comment: Заходили-то жёны, я так понимаю? У Вас просто выходит, что сами дипломаты.))

Comment: Да, "зашедшими" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы согласился, что *обморок восторга* — авторская находка, но без *упасть*. В таком случае *обморок восторга* — некоторое обморочно-восторженное состояние, в которое впадают, погружаются (или входят другим образом), но не падают.

Comment: Кажется, это до революции  впадали в обморок,  потом стали просто падать. После этих слов император впал в обморок. [П. И. Ковалевский. Наполеон I и его гений (1900-1910)]   А устаревшее слово может иметь ироничный характер. К тому же сочетание с двумя В плохо читается.

Answer (score 1):

**Конечно, свежий образ, вам придется его оставить.**

От восторга ― это так банально. Кстати, писатели пытались экспериментировать с "обмороком", находя для него определения (правда, согласованные):

Он погрузился в обморок, **чёрный, долгий, омерзительный**. [И. Грекова. Фазан (1984)]

Подъезжая к Белеву, сделался мне **прелютейший** обморок. [Д. И. Фонвизин. Отрывки из дневника четвертого заграничного путешествия (1786-1787)]

Состояние это напоминает обморок, **в чье игольное ушко** беззвучно просачивается тонкая струйка жизни. [Дина Рубина. Медная шкатулка (сборник) (2015)]

Есть еще такие термины, как **«национальный обморок»** ― от Дмитрия Лихачева...// «Знание - сила», 2011]

Answer (score 1):

Я бы эту свежесть преобразовал в "**полуобморок** (восторга)", ведь новое состояние не связано с потерей сознания или ощущений. Это роднило бы первую её часть с более изящным "полумраком".

Comment: Юмор оценён по достоинству. )))